# How do I create Warped arc text in Adobe Illustrator with better symmetry?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I create warped arc text using the AI warp tool, it never seems to have great symmetry.  Take a look at this example:

[image: Warped arc text]

To me, this graphic does not look symmetrical.  The graphic looks pushed to the right.  It seems Adobe Illustrator aligns the graphic with the top of the W, and the top of the N on the Y-axis.

Is it possible to align the curve based on the bottom of the W and the bottom of the N on the X-axis?  Is there a quick setting/fix for this?

If not, how do I make this graphic seem more in align?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You.

Wyatt

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned this, but if you measure [with a guide along the top of the letters W and N](https://i.imgur.com/38Tv3Kx.png), they  are actually symmetrical - so if you rotate that text to make bottom corner of the W touch the same baseline as the N, then the top will no longer be symmetrical. Either way, some symmetry will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is using a *dummy* shape:

- Group the text with a little shape at the right
- Apply from **Menu Effect** > **Warp** > **Arc** to the group
- With the **Direct Selection Tool** select the shape and move it to the left until the text get aligned as you want
- Set the shape with transparent fill and no stroke

[image: Dummy shape]

Comment: Great solution!  Unfortunately, I'm hoping to automate this with data-driven graphics.  Do you know of a solution that does not require the human eye to manually make it symmetrical?  I'm guessing I will need to use envelope distortion.

Comment: Sure there Will be a solution without the human eye. Are you sure all the words where you will apply this solution start with W?

Comment: Well, I guess I could make 26 different solutions for each alphabet letter.  And run my data-driven graphics 26 times.  Think I could do this with actions?  What are you thinking?

Comment: What I think is that you are looking for a generic solution for an exception, and that will bring you more work than you suppose. Maybe you should include in the question the complete solution you want to reach, avoiding the exception. It will be easier to get an adequate answer.

Comment: I agree. @WyattJackson you asked for a quick solution and here it is. If you want an automated solution for data-driven graphics, that's a different, more complex question.

Comment: I'm processing hundreds of thousands of graphics.  Not really an exception.  I need this arc to be symmetrical no matter what word is inputted via data-driven graphics.  How would I go about making it automatically symmetrical for all words starting with the letter W?

Comment: @WyattJackson The arc is symmetrical it doesn't get simmetrical in your exception. If you use a word starting with a M and ending with a E, it's perfectly symmetrical. Maybe this is not the question and arc is not the solution. Using Text on a Path you can align the text with the ascenders, and the baseline is aligned. Or use another font, one with the W without inclined strokes.

Comment: @Luciano Rotating the text in a wraping arc probably you get some text distortion. With the shape the only distortion is the Arc, the text is always in a horizontal baseline.

Comment: you're right: I just tested here and it's very clear. Ignore my silly question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have better control over the text, use a text on a path. There you can rotate the text to get a better alignment.

Create an arc or ellipse, type your text on it, adjust.